# Can you limit the number of tries on biometrics prompt in React Native using keychain?

Tags: react-native, keychain, biometrics

Is there a possibility to limit the numbers of biometric tries before lockout in React Native using keychain. The point is to limit the user to 3 tries instead of 5, so it doesn't come to lockout.

```
const result = await Keychain.getGenericPassword({
      ...keychainOptions,
)};
```